# Can "secret" be set to the default phase of mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-phases

I would like to create "secret" commit instead of "draft" commit by default in a mercurial project. Is there any way to configure mercurial so that the default phase is "secret" instead of "draft" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `hg help phases`

```
To make yours commits secret by default, put this in your configuration
file:

  [phases]
  new-commit = secret
```

Comment: Which Mercurial version are you using? I am using Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.9)

Comment: 2.8.2, from ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ```hg help phase``` is different from ```hg help phases```


  - ```hg help phase``` is for information on manually manipulating phases
  - ```hg help phases``` explains what phases are